# i is not Accessed Pylance

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

```py
def main():                                                # function definition
    print("This program illustrates a chaotic funciton.")  # output statement
    x = eval(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: "))    # assignment statement wrapped around input statement
    for i in range(10):                                    # loop statement
        x = 3.9 * x * (1 - x)                              # expression
        print(x)                                           # output statement
```

The for loop line of code shows an error that says i is not Accessed Pylance, which means the Pylance extension is not using the same binary as the project. How can I make it use the same binary?

Since this line of code came from John Zelles Python programming textbook, I switched from python 3.11.2 to python 3.5.2 since the book is quite old and possibly the syntax has changed with the updates, however I still am not able to run the code.

Comment: they probably have added a few lint rules, python is backwards compatible with syntax if you keep the major number (`3.x`) the same

Comment: you don't call the function `main()`, this is not C/C++ where `main()` is called by the C/C++ library initialization routine

Comment: The that's all the code you have, it won't give you any output. The code is technically valid but it just runs and immediately stops without really doing anything. It won't automatically call a function just because you call it "main"

Comment: So if def main(): is deleted and the indentation is shifted over by one it should print the string and 10 numbers below, however the problem with the for loop still remains as indicated by visual studio code highlighting it in red. @qrsngky

Comment: @Kaden It doesn't cause any runtime error in the Python interpreter. But to satisfy the linter, since you're not going to use `i` anywhere in the loop, just use `_` instead

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use the loop variable use the variable name: `_`

```py
# ...
for _ in range(10):
   x = 3.9 * x * (1 - x)
```

Comment: Using the variable name which I assume is x is not guarantied to loop a constant 10 times.

Comment: @Kaden You should read a good book about Python programming and understand what a `for` loop does. There are good websites too. There are also very poor sites.

Comment: I’m reading John Zelle’s textbook an introductory to python programming… are you saying there is a better option? @rioV8

Comment: @Kaden the loop variable in your OP case is `i`